# Symfony2: Displaying session variable in a twig throw exception

Tags: php, symfony, session

I have a session variable like this in a controller

```
$session->set('data', array(
                      'address'=>$form->get('address')->getData(),
                      'detail'=>$form->get('detail')->getData(),
                      'email'=>$form->get('phone')->getData(),
                  ));
```

I am getting it in another controller like this

```
$session = $request->getSession();
        $data = $session->get("data");
```

If I try to access the above session in a twig file it throws exception

```
{{ app.session.get('data') }}
```

Please how do I display the above session data in a twig file
Please what could be wrong?

Comment: Look at the structure of my question, you will see that there are not thesame

Comment: Mine throws exception....

Comment: I see accepted answer which is the same as in linked question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do something like this

```
{% set data = app.session.get('data') %}
{{ data['address'] }}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I print the above over a printer.